# AngularJS Cannot read property 'getData' of undefined in VS

Tags: json, angularjs

do you know what I am doing wrong? I want to read data from my json-file but i got the error that it can´t read the property getData.

```
myApp.service('jsonDataService', function ($http) {
this.getData = function () {
    return $http({
        method: 'GET',
        url: '/jsonData/Stations.json'
    });
  }
});
```

controller:

```
myApp.controller('IndexController', ['$scope', function ($scope, jsonDataService) { 
jsonDataService.getData().then(function (msg) {
    $scope.msg = msg;
    console.log(msg);
   });
}]);
```

I am using ng in Visual studio in a mvc project.

path json-file: " Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Test\WebApplication\Scripts\jsonData\Stations.json"

Comment: change controller to : myApp.controller('IndexController', ['$scope', 'jsonDataService', function ($scope, jsonDataService)

Comment: Have you injected jsonDataService properly? Your Inline Array Annotation is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the controller code which you have shared, you have not injected 'jsonDataService' service properly.

It should be:

```
myApp.controller('IndexController', ['$scope', 'jsonDataService', function ($scope, jsonDataService) { 
    jsonDataService.getData().then(function (msg) {
    $scope.msg = msg;
    console.log(msg);
   });
}]);
```